# limes(a/b) = c => lim(a = b * c)

Tags: sequences-and-series, analysis, limits

Is this expression right:  $\displaystyle \lim_{k \to \infty} (\frac{{a}_{k+1}}{{a}_{k}})= c  \Rightarrow \lim_{k \to \infty} a_{k+1} = a_{k} * c$ ? It seems logical to me.

And if it is right where would I put the brackets?

1. $\displaystyle \lim_{k \to \infty} (a_{k+1} = a_{k} * c) $ or 2. $\displaystyle \lim_{k \to \infty} (a_{k+1}) = a_{k} * c $

The second one doesn't seem right to me, but I am not sure if the first one is allowed..

Comment: What do you mean by $*$ ?

Comment: @EnjoysMath multiplication

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Neither of your formulas 1 & 2 makes sense.  The first purports to be the limit of an equation, yet there is no notion of distance or topology given on the set of equations.  The second has a left side that has nothing to do with $k$ (it would be the same as $\lim_{n\to\infty}a_{n+1}$) while the right side can vary with $k$.

The fundamental problems with your idea of multiplying both sides of the original equation by $a_k$ are (a) $k$ is only a bound variable in the original equation, meaning that the left side doesn't depend on any choice of a value for $k$, so it's not clear which $a_k$ you want to multiply by, and (b) $\lim_{k\to\infty}a_{k+1}$ might not exist, and the same goes for $\lim_{k\to\infty}ca_k$.

Comment: @Andreas_Blass Thanks for the answer. Ok, so how would I put something like that then? If lim(a_k+1/a_k) = c tells me that the limit of dividing them both for k->infty will be c. how could I put that, so that I can say something like that means if k->infty a_k+1 will be c * a_k... or is that just wrong? (seems all logical to me): if lim(a_k+1/a_k) = 2 then a_k+1 will be 2 * a_k for k->infty or not?

Comment: @gumble: It's not clear what you mean by "for k -> infty", because then there isn't any particular value of k any more (infty isn't a value), so what are $a_k$ and $a_{k+1}$ in this context? The closest reasonable statement I can think of to what you're saying is that, if the $a_k$'s are positive, then for every positive $\varepsilon$, there is some $M$ such that $(c-\varepsilon)a_k<a_{k+1}<(c+\varepsilon)a_k$.